# How to fix webpack Error: Cannot find module - on node.js (webpackEmptyContext)

Tags: node.js, webpack

My `webpack.config.js`  is :

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app.ts',
  target: 'node',
  node: {
    __dirname: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

When I build my project and run it I am getting the following error:

```
(node:51071) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module '../gather/gatherers/css-usage'
    at webpackEmptyContext (webpack:///./node_modules/lighthouse/lighthouse-core/config_sync?:2:10)
    at Function.requireGathererFr
```

This error is raised from a 3rd party library I am using - `lighthouse`.

How to fix this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For target as node, you might have to use this package `webpack-node-externals` in order to ignore all modules in `node_module` folder. Then declare as `externals`:

```js
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  // ...
};
```